# Altium: Rectangular clearance around rectangular pads

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I am designing a high voltage PCB so I have created clearance rules between nets equal to the pad spacing on the high voltage capacitors (4.5 mm). When I pour polygons, Altium appears to produce rectangular clearances around the pads for the capacitors. This probably does not matter with small clearances but with larger clearances I get large notches in polygons. Is there a way round this?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: So you have a clearance rule, and you want to be able to ignore that clearance rule? I would just move the offending parts, so you can maintain your desired clearances.

Comment: No, that's not what I want to do. I want to obtain the minimum clearance around a rectangular pad, no more, no less. That is not a rectangular area.

Comment: milled air gap for creepage is best

Comment: Please highlight the notches in your layout that are bothering you.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

- klick on problematic pad,
- in properties, change pad shape from "rectangular" to "rounded rectangle" and set corner radius to 1%
- repour polygon